# Why pool class in multiprocessing is not giving advantage over linear processing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to measure the advantage of **pool class** in **multiprocessing module** over normal programming and I am calculating square of a number using a function . Now when I calculate the time take to find the square of all the three numbers it takes around **~0.24 sec** but when I calculate it normally in a for loop it takes even less **~0.007 sec**. Why is that? Shouldn't the code part with pool should be faster?

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool,Process

def f(x):
   return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':

   start = time.time()
   array = []
   for i in range(1000000):
       array.append(i)

   with Pool(4) as p:
       (p.map(f, array))

   print(time.time()-start)  # time taken when using pool

   start1 = time.time()



   for i in range(1000000):
       f(array[i])



   print(time.time()-start1)   # time taken normaly
```

Comment: Your task is too simple. The overhead of creating the process will eat up all advantages.

Comment: so what changes should I make in this to have a significant value, please help

Comment: Give it some significant work to do. Usually everything that takes longer that 100ms is worse spawning a process.

Comment: Add `time.sleep(3)` to the function if you just want to see a difference.

Comment: @KlausD. I have now taken 1 million values still the linear one is faster

Comment: @wwii let me try

Comment: You don't have to spawn more processes, you have to give them longer running work to do.

Comment: thanks @KlausD.  and wwii for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suggested by @klaus D. and @wwii I was not having enough computation to overcome the overhead of spawning processes and the time taken in switching between the processes.
Below is the updated code to notice the difference. Hope it helps

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool,Process

def f(x):
    time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    array = []

    for i in range(4):
        array.append(i)

    start = time.time()

    with Pool(4) as p:
        (p.map(f, array))

    print(time.time()-start)  # time taken when using pool

    start1 = time.time()



    for i in range(4):
        f(array[i])



    print(time.time()-start1)   # time taken normaly
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function for workers in pool is too simple to be improved by parallelism:

try this:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool,Process

N = 80
M = 1_000_000

def f_std(array):
    """
    Calculate Standard deviation
    """
    mean = sum(array)/len(array)
    std = ((sum(map(lambda x: (x-mean)**2, array)))/len(array))**.5
    return std

if __name__ == '__main__':

    array = []
    for i in range(N):
        array.append(range(M))

    start = time.time()

    with Pool(8) as p:
        (p.map(f_std, array))
    print(time.time()-start)  # time taken when using pool


    start1 = time.time()

    for i in range(N):
        f_std(array[i])
    print(time.time()-start1)   # time taken normaly
```